# how to update element name in a xml column in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I have an xml column in my table like following:

```
   <info>
      <teacher>     
            <name>John</name>   
      </teacher>
      <StInfo>
        <name>William</name>    
        <address>India</address>    
      </StInfo>
    </info>
```

I have to just update  to

```
 <info>
          <teacher>     
                <name>John</name>   
          </teacher>
          <Student>
            <name>William</name>    
            <address>India</address>    
          </Student>
        </info>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've built an example for you in SQL Server using your data:

```
DECLARE @StackExample TABLE (
     Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT(NEWID())
    ,XmlColumn XML
)

INSERT INTO @StackExample(XmlColumn) VALUES('<info>
  <StInfo>
    <name>William</name>    
    <address>India</address>    
  </StInfo>
</info>')


UPDATE T
SET XmlColumn = XmlColumn.query('<info>
  <Student>
  {info/StInfo/*}
  </Student>
</info>')
FROM @StackExample t

SELECT * FROM @StackExample
```

I hope this can help

Comment: it's working but sorry i have not given complete structure of xml as there are some other elemts too at <stinfo> level which get removed after execution, i have updated xml in question

Comment: You simply add {info/teacher} before <Student> tag in the update statement and it's done . Sorry but I can't test it, but i want to sent you a fast response to give you the change to try.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to modify xml element names with SQL DML. You can replace it after converting to varchar:

```
update Table1 set
    data = cast(
      replace(
        replace(
          cast(data as nvarchar(max)),
        '</StInfo>', '</Student>'
        ),
      '<StInfo>', '<Student>'
      )
    as xml)
```

Or you can reconstruct your xml using XQuery:

```
update Table1 set
    data = data.query('<info>{
                for $i in info/StInfo
                return element Student {$i/*}
                }</info>'
    )
```

These appoaches will work even for multiple elements.

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24958)</kbd>**